# How to unit test an xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, unit-testing

I have an XSD schema already for the following xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
 <to> </to>
 <from> </from>
 <datetime>  </datetime>
 <heading> </heading>
 <body> </body>
</note>
```

I implemented a NoteGnerator to generate xml files based on the schema. The xml files must have to generated regarding some templates/specifications, such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
 <to> Lucy </to>
 <from> Lily </from>
 <datetime> --date--time-- </datetime>
 <heading> reminder </heading>
 <body> do not forget my pen </body>
</note>
```

Another template/specification would be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
 <to> Lily </to>
 <from> Lucy </from>
 <datetime> --date--time-- </datetime>
 <heading> reply </heading>
 <body> no problem </body>
</note>
```

, where `<datetime>` is a dynamic value when the xml is generated (so this value cannot be predetermined). Based on the XSD scheme and these two XML specifications, I can easily generate XML messages.

How can I unit test the generated XML files?

Do I need to validate the generated XML files again the schema? Or I need to use some diff tool to compare the generated xml files and the template? Because the datetime is dynamic, it is different each time when an xml file is generated, so how to compare them with the template? Or I need to deserialise xml to c# object and then test the c# object ?

Comment: Your XSD schema is not an XSD schema. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29 on how a schema looks like. It should start with `<xs:schema>`.

Comment: Yes it is not a schema. what I meant was that I have a schema for that xml file

Comment: What is it exactly you want to unit test?

Comment: I would like to test whether the generated xml files are correct according to the given templates, for instance the two ones I gave above.

Comment: @user3118189 Please distinguish correctness according a template and correctness according a schema. What happens, if you insert `<b>Bold heading</b>` as the heading? It still looks like a valid heading, but might break your schema.

Comment: @user3118189 If you just want to check document validity, validate against the schema. If you want to validate the data content, parse the document and validate the data. Dates for example could be validated as a _valid_ date, not a specific date. Another alternative is to mock the data source and compare the data contents exactly.

Comment: How risky is your implementation? Do you use string manipulation, e.g. `string.Replace("<to> </to>", "<to> " + receiver + "</to>")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily compare generated XML node values, except from the `datetime`. This is because of its non-deterministic nature. In unit testing (and code design) such problems are usually solved in either of two ways:

- removing non-determinism altogether
- loosening your requirements relating to non-determinism (eg. by not performing exact matching but rather some sort of fuzzy/approximated one)

With first solution, your note generating component would need to abstract out *current date time* to external service/dependency, say:

```
public class NoteGenerator
{
    private readonly ICurrentDateProvider currentDateProvider;
    public NoteGenerator(ICurrentDateProvider )currentDateProvider
    {
        this.currentDateProvider = currentDateProvider;
    }

    public string GenerateNote()
    {
        var currentDate = currentDateProvider.Now;
        // ...
```

Now in unit test you can *fake* that dependency using your isolation framework of choice and perform assertions against deterministic value you set yourself (example with [FakeItEasy](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy)):

```
var dateProvider = A.Fake<ICurrentDateProvider>();
A.CallTo(() => dateProvider.Now).Returns(new DateTime(2014, 01, 31, 10, 30));
var generator = new NoteGenerator(dateProvider);

// ...
```

The second approach is to replace the *date time must be this value*-matching with *date time must not be older than*-matching, for example:

```
var oneMinuteAgo = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1.0);
var generator = new NoteGenerator();

var dateFromXml = // extract 
Assert.That(dateFromXml, Is.GreaterThan(oneMinuteAgo));
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful for you. In this I am creating a object, assigning values, writing it to XML, reading the XML, and comparing it to original object. I am assuming that you have whole class structure.

```
// This is your expected object which you are going to write to xml.
var sourceObject = new SomeClassToWriteInXML();

// Writing object to XML.
var document = new XDocument();
var serializer = new XMLSerializer(typeof(SomeClassToWriteInXML));
using (var writer = document .CreateWriter())
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, source);
}
// write document to a file.

// Now document has the XML document.
// Need to read file you have just created. For testing sake I am reading document.
var actual = new SomeClassToWriteInXML();
// Deserialize xml to get actual object (which should be equal to sourceObject)
using (var reader = document.CreateReader())
{
    actual = (SomeClassToWriteInXML)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}

Assert.AreEqual(expected.First(), actual.First());
```

Comment: how many use cases you can test without preparing xml files (error prone task as well) using this method?